# cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time + the variable is a mutable queue

Tags: rust, reference, tree, borrow-checker, mutable

I'm trying to traverse a graph and extract a sub-tree out of it based on the criteria which is defined in my code. The details of the graph or the criteria is not important. However, the process of creating the tree has been very challenging due to the complexity of references and borrowing in rust. I'm not pro in rust.

To make it simple, I have 2 functions:

1. The first one gets the graph, the depth of graph to traverse and return a sub-tree of type ScriptTree which is a struct.

```
fn run_subsequent_scripts(&self, graph: &PageGraph, depth: usize) ->  ScriptTree {
    let mut level: usize;
    let mut visited: HashMap<NodeId, bool> = HashMap::new();
    // create a queue for BFS
    let mut queue = vec![];
    // Starting vertex maked as visited and added to queueu
    let script_info = get_script_info(graph, self.query.id);
    let mut root = ScriptTree::new(script_info.0 ,script_info.1, script_info.2);
    
    visited.insert(self.query.id, true);
    queue.push(&mut root);
    
    let mut level_meter: Vec<NodeId> = Vec::new();
    
    // continue until queue is empty
    while queue.len() != 0 && level_meter.len() < depth {
        level = queue.len();

        while level != 0 {
          // Get the front of the queue and remove it
          let mut child_node: ScriptTree;
          let parent_node = queue.remove(0);
          level -= 1;
          // Get all adjacent vertices from that vertex
          // neighbors of the parent
          let neighbors: Vec<NodeId> = get_injected_scripts(&graph,    parent_node.script_info.script_node_id, &Action::script());
          let mut neighbor_nodes: Vec<ScriptTree> = Vec::new();
          for child_id in neighbors {
              if !visited.contains_key(&child_id) {
              //mark as visited
              visited.insert(child_id, true);
              // push back to check this vertex's vertices
              let child_script_info = get_script_info(graph, child_id);
              child_node = ScriptTree::new(child_script_info.0, child_script_info.1, child_script_info.2);
              queue.push(&mut child_node);
              neighbor_nodes.push(child_node);
              level_meter.push(child_id);
              }
          }
        self.update_tree(&mut root, &parent_node, neighbor_nodes);
        }
        level += 1;
    } 
  return root
  }
```

2. The second function updates the tree by adding the children of the parent_node captured in node_neighbors vectored in the previous function:

```
fn update_tree(&self, subtree: &mut ScriptTree, parent_node: &ScriptTree, node_neighbors: Vec<ScriptTree>) {
    if subtree.node_id == parent_node.node_id {
      // Return a reference to this node if it has the target ID
      for child in node_neighbors{
        subtree.add_child(child);
      }
    }
    else {

      // Recursively search the children of this node
      for mut child in &subtree.children {
          self.update_tree(&mut child, parent_node, node_neighbors);
      }
    }    
  }
```

This code gives me error in multiple lines:

In function 1,

- In line `child_node = ScriptTree::new(child_script_info.0, child_script_info.1, child_script_info.2);` it says "cannot assign to `child_node` because it is borrowed assignment to borrowed `child_node` occurs here".
- In line `queue.push(&mut child_node);` it says "cannot borrow `child_node` as mutable more than once at a time `child_node` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop"
- In line `neighbor_nodes.push(child_node);` it says "cannot move out of `child_node` because it is borrowed move out of `child_node` occurs here"
- and in line `self.update_tree(&mut root, &parent_node, neighbor_nodes);` it says "cannot borrow `root` as mutable more than once at a time second mutable borrow occurs here"

In function 2:

- In line `self.update_tree( &mut child, parent_node, node_neighbors);` it says:

1. cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable cannot borrow as mutable
2. use of moved value: `node_neighbors` value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

I appreciate any help to solve the issue!

Comment: You should consider a rewrite. In function 2:
- you expect a mutable reference to be an alias of a immutable reference which is prevented by the borrow checker
- you immutably borrow `&subtree.children` assigning it to a variable `mut child` you expect to be mutable
- you have an owned var `node_neighbours` that you pass recursively expecting to reuse it afterwards (giving away the ownership prevents any changes afterwards)

Comment: As pointed out  by CoronA your code has several issues, you might want to step back and familiarize yourself a little more with the language, writing a correct graph, tree or even linked list is *very hard* in Rust and should not be attempted by someone relatively new to the language without some guidance. You might want to check out [Entirely too many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) which goes over a lot of the pitfalls you encounter while implementing them, it helped me tremendously in understanding the borrow checker.

Comment: @CoronA Thanks for the guidance! I addressed the errors in function 2. Now, there is only one issue: In function 1, I need to assign child_node to two vectors. 
queue.push(child_node);
neighbor_nodes.push(child_node);
But the point is that queue expected `&mut ScriptTree` and when I change it, the second vector complains "cannot move out of `child_node` because it is borrowed". Is there any way to address it?

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for sending over the link. Really appreciate it. I'm gonna work on it.

Comment: Try to put your code into a [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). It is quite hard to give solutions on code that is only visible in fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `run_subsequent_scripts`:

- Change `let mut child_node: ScriptTree` to `let child_node: ScriptTree`.

  - Declare `child_node` without initializing it, which allows assigning to it later without borrowing it mutably.
- Change `queue.push(&mut root)` to `queue.push(root)`.

  - Pass a non-mutable reference to root to the queue, which should allow us to borrow it mutably later.
- Change `let mut neighbor_nodes: Vec<ScriptTree> = Vec::new()` to `let mut neighbor_nodes = Vec::with_capacity(neighbors.len())`.

  - Pre-allocate the neighbor_nodes vector with enough capacity to hold all the neighbors, which should avoid the need for any reallocation that might cause issues with borrowing.
- Change the loop where you iterate over the `neighbor_nodes` vector to use `for child_node in node_neighbors.into_iter()` instead.

  - Consume the `node_neighbors` vector and allows moving the `ScriptTree` values out of it without borrowing them.

In `update_tree`:

- Change `for mut child in &subtree.children` to `for child in &mut subtree.children`.

  - Allows borrowing the children of subtree mutably, which is necessary to update them.

**Updated Code with sample inputs ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f94b8666e6b01e113f2332a5e254f6e4)):**

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct NodeId(u32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PageGraph;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct ScriptInfo(u32, u32, u32);

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct ScriptTree {
    script_info: ScriptInfo,
    children: Vec<ScriptTree>,
}

impl ScriptTree {
    fn new(a: u32, b: u32, c: u32) -> Self {
        ScriptTree {
            script_info: ScriptInfo(a, b, c),
            children: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_child(&mut self, child: ScriptTree) {
        self.children.push(child);
    }
}

enum Action {
    Script,
}

fn get_injected_scripts(
    _graph: &PageGraph,
    _node_id: u32,
    _action: &Action,
) -> Vec<NodeId> {
    vec![NodeId(1), NodeId(2), NodeId(3)]
}

fn get_script_info(_graph: &PageGraph, _node_id: NodeId) -> ScriptInfo {
    ScriptInfo(1, 2, 3)
}

struct Query {
    id: NodeId,
}

struct Example {
    query: Query,
}

impl Example {
    fn run_subsequent_scripts(&self, graph: &PageGraph, depth: usize) -> ScriptTree {
        let mut level: usize = 0;
        let mut visited: HashMap<NodeId, bool> = HashMap::new();
        let mut queue = vec![];
        let script_info = get_script_info(graph, self.query.id.clone());
        let mut root = ScriptTree::new(script_info.0, script_info.1, script_info.2);

        visited.insert(self.query.id.clone(), true);
        queue.push(root.clone());

        let mut level_meter: Vec<NodeId> = Vec::new();

        while !queue.is_empty() && level < depth {
            let level_size = queue.len();

            for _ in 0..level_size {
                let mut neighbor_nodes = Vec::new();
                let parent_node = queue.remove(0);
                let neighbors = get_injected_scripts(&graph, parent_node.script_info.0, &Action::Script);

                for child_id in neighbors {
                    if !visited.contains_key(&child_id) {
                        visited.insert(child_id.clone(), true);
                        let child_script_info = get_script_info(graph, child_id.clone());
                        let child_node = ScriptTree::new(
                            child_script_info.0,
                            child_script_info.1,
                            child_script_info.2,
                        );
                        queue.push(child_node.clone());
                        neighbor_nodes.push(child_node);
                        level_meter.push(child_id);
                    }
                }
                self.update_tree(&mut root, &parent_node, neighbor_nodes);
            }
            level += 1;
        }
        root
    }

    fn update_tree(
        &self,
        subtree: &mut ScriptTree,
        parent_node: &ScriptTree,
        node_neighbors: Vec<ScriptTree>,
    ) {
        if subtree.script_info.0 == parent_node.script_info.0 {
            for child_node in node_neighbors {
                subtree.add_child(child_node);
            }
        } else {
            for child in &mut subtree.children {
                self.update_tree(child, parent_node, node_neighbors.clone());
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let graph = PageGraph;
    let example = Example {
        query: Query { id: NodeId(1) },
    };
    let depth = 1;
    let script_tree = example.run_subsequent_scripts(&graph, depth);
    println!("{:#?}", script_tree);
}
```

Best practice: Providing a minimum viable example code (in question) that can be executable by others.

Comment: Hi @jishan-shaikh, thanks for the detailed answer! I made your suggested changes. It prompts other errors: Now in the update_tree function, in the line where says "for child in neighbor_nodes {  subtree.add_child(child);  }", child is a mismatch type and says expected struct `ScriptTree`, found `&&ScriptTree`. When I try to change the add_child method which is implemented for struct ScriptTree, it causes other errors. Like, I have to change the children filed to Vec<&Scripts> and this asks me to include "expected named lifetime parameter"

Comment: @PounehBahrami Edit: Added playground for reference and an example

Comment: Thanks @jishan-shaikh!!! Really appreciate it ♡  
It solved the issue. I was literally struggling with that for a week :)) and it seems like I can't vote your answer b.c I don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow! sorry about that...

Comment: Thanks, happy to help. Don't worry about the upvote, I think you can still accept the answer.